# How can I programmatically set adjustViewBounds to true in Android?

Tags: android, imageview, scaling

I want to set `adjustViewBounds` property of my `ImageView` to true, programmatically, not in XML. How can this be done?

Answer (score 44):

Call [ImageView#setAdjustViewBounds(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds%28boolean%29).

Comment: Thanks, why I did not try it myself?!

Comment: @Fanria - that's a great question `;-P`